# NextJs not found page keeps reloading every ~ 3 seconds

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm following this https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found

but everything worked fine but the not found page keeps reloading every second. here is my not found page code

```
    import Link from "next/link";

export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div className="overflow-hidden bg-white text-black md:py-20">
      <div className="container relative mx-auto px-4">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 items-center px-4 py-20 xl:py-10">
          <div>
            <h2 className="relative z-10 text-center text-6xl font-bold xl:text-9xl">
              Oops! <br /> Page Not Found
            </h2>
            <span className="absolute left-0 top-0 w-full transform whitespace-nowrap text-[250px] font-extrabold text-gray-400 opacity-40 blur-[2px] md:-left-[5%] xl:text-[300px]">
              ERROR 404
            </span>
            <p className="mx-auto text-center text-base md:p-4 xl:w-2/3 xl:text-xl">
              Don&apos;t worry, though! Our team of skilled developers is
              constantly working to enhance your browsing experience. In the
              meantime, feel free to explore our other amazing content and
              discover exciting insights.
              <br />
              If you believe you&apos;ve reached this page in error, please
              double-check the URL or use the navigation links to find your way
              back to our website&apos;s main sections.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Next.js, and it has been [reported on GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10024). Apparently, it only happens during development mode (`npm run dev`), but no issues in the production mode (`npm run build && npm start`.

I've noticed that you're using the `Link` component and that's [probably the issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51132#issuecomment-1590040861).

> It seems that, when we throw `notFound()`, it works fine. But, when we use other ways like `router.push()` or `Link` component, This error happens.

So removing `import Link from "next/link";` should make it work for you since you're not using it.

Some people also [reported using turbopack](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10024#issuecomment-1422575933) fixes the issue as well.

> As a temporary solution, using turbopack with the `npm next dev --turbo` command seems to fix it for me.

Comment: I just checked. as you have said. in production the issue isn't found. and I don't think using the Link is causing the issue. I removed Link import but the issue still exists. and I want to use Link cause I've add button that will take user to home page or any other page when clicked in not found page.

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING I'm honestly quite disappointed that the issue isn't resolved yet. If I find any workarounds for this issue, I'll surely update my answer. Also, once Next.js fixes this issue I'll update the answer as well.

Comment: well... if it's not causing any issue in prod build then it's fine.. i guess 